# Генератор алгоритмов по конечным значениям

Tags: алгоритм, кодогенераторы

Интересно, есть ли такой генератор, который по нескольким конечным данным, может высчитать алгоритм генерации этих данных? Интересны трезвые мнения насколько возможно/невозможно такой сделать.
Как известно, ключи для программ генерируются по своим алгоритмам. И если десяток этих ключей поместить в эту программу она будет пытаться просчитать этот алгоритм. Например формулы каких-то последовательностей, мы просто вставляем значений 10 в программу, а она считает алгоритм. Либо с какими-то известными параметрами, которые могут помочь программе выявить алгоритм. Например формулы физические при известных константах или при каком-то конкретном значении. Давно была такая идея, мне вот интересны мнения

Comment: Всё что было когда либо написано или будет написано уже есть в вавилонской библиотеке https://libraryofbabel.info/

Comment: Слишком обширный вопрос. И множество крупных тем затрагивает: машинное обучение, криптографию, безопасность... На каждый _конкретный_ вопрос есть конкретный ответ, но на столь общий вопрос ответа нет. Поэтому голосую за его закрытие.

Answer (score 4):

Каждое конечное число элементов может быть порождено бесконечным числом алгоритмов, даже с учётом здравого смысла (то есть если отбросить какие-то совершенно бредовые алгоритмы). Вот я дам Вам последовательность чисел и ваша программа угадает, что они являются корнями какого-то полинома (а это всегда так и будет, кстати), а я имел в виду потенциалы транспортных потоков в дивергентном поле выпуклых комбинаций почти строгих дифференциалов... Вы могли это хотя бы предвидеть? Не думаю. Поэтому вероятность что-то угадать в такой постановке вопроса равна НУЛЮ (единицу поделить на бесконечность).

Нужно конкретизировать вопрос. Скажем, ранее я занимался выводом рациональных производящих функций по заданной последовательности чисел. Дано несколько целых чисел, точно известно, что она порождена некоторой рациональной производящей функцией - найти эту функцию. Это можно сделать всегда, когда число элементов не меньше удвоенной степени знаменателя искомой функции. В остальных случаях этого сделать нельзя. Но это очень узкая область и совершенно точно известна специфика алгоритма, который мы ищем (производящие функции, причём рациональные).